# Apache Camel Mock ProducerTemplate Endpoint

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I want to mock the mail sending not to send mail in unit testing.

My code is below:

```
@Component("utilityRoutes")
public class UtilityRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("seda:sendEmail")
    .routeId("utilityRoutes")   
    .setHeader("from", simple("{{email.from}}"))        
    .setHeader("contentType", constant("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"))

    .choice()
        .when(header(Constants.HEADER_EMAIL_TARGET).isEqualTo("AAA"))
            .setHeader("to", simple("{{recipients-a}}"))
        .when(header(Constants.HEADER_EMAIL_TARGET).isEqualTo("BBB"))
            .setHeader("to", simple("{{recipients-b}}"))
    .end()

    .to("{{email.url}}")
    .id("emailUrl");

  }

}
```

My Test Case is:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { RailMLExport.class })
@DirtiesContext
public class UtilityRoutesTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  @Autowired
  CamelContext camelContext;

  @Produce(uri = "seda:sendEmail")
  ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @EndpointInject(uri="mock:emailEndpoint")
  MockEndpoint mailEndpoint;

  @Override
  public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String isMockEndpoints() {
    return "*";
  }

  @Test
  public void testSendAndReceiveMail() throws Exception {

    camelContext.getRouteDefinition("utilityRoutes").adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveById("emailUrl").after().to("mock:emailEndpoint");
        }
    }

    );
    camelContext.start();
    Collection<Endpoint> endpoints = camelContext.getEndpoints();
    for (Endpoint endpoint : endpoints) {
        System.err.println(endpoint.getEndpointUri());
    }

    mailEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    mailEndpoint.expectedBodyReceived();

    Map<String,Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(Constants.HEADER_EMAIL_TARGET,"AAA");
    headers.put(Constants.HEADER_EMAIL_SUBJECT, "CCC");

    producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders("seda:sendEmail", "test", headers);
    mailEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();

  }
}
```

I give error as follows.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ProducerTemplate has not been started
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.getProducerCache(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:689)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:148)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:267)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:317)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:313)
  at fi.vr.h.ivu.integration.railmlexport.routes.UtilityRoutesTest.testSendAndReceiveMail(UtilityRoutesTest.java:89)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
  at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
  at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: You need to use mockAndSkip if you don't want to send to that original endpoint

Comment: Should I add it to adviceWIth method?

Comment: See Roland's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either overwrite [`isMockEndpointsAndSkip`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-test/apidocs/org/apache/camel/test/junit4/CamelTestSupport.html#isMockEndpointsAndSkip()) or use [`adviceWith`](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) as you mentioned and skip it in that AdviceWithRoute. You can even [intercept your exchange](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html) and call [`skipSendToOriginalEndpoint`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/InterceptSendToEndpointDefinition.html#skipSendToOriginalEndpoint--) from there. Different possible ways to accomplish what you want.

A further note: You probably shouldn't use `"*"` in `isMockEndpoints` (or `isMockEndpointsAndSkip`), except you want to mock every route. Just mention the routes you really want to mock. This way it is more clear for other programmers watching your code what you really are mocking and what not.